# Undefined Reference to `SDL2_Init` with LD when G++ is not giving an error

Tags: c++, mingw, sdl-2, ld, undefined-reference

I'm trying to setup SDL2 with MinGW and I have everything set up beside one thing. Whenever I try to compile G++ gives no errors but then LD gives me a: `undefined reference to SDL_Init` Error.

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc28dE2R.o: in function `SDL_main':
C:\Users\user\Documents\SDL2/src/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\Documents\SDL2/src/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\Documents\SDL2/src/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `IMG_Init'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\Documents\SDL2/src/main.cpp:20: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g src\*.cpp -o build\game.exe -ID:C:\MinGW\include -LD:C:\MinGW\lib -mwindows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2_image -lSDL2" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

I have tried to move the args around. doing `-mwindows`, adding `-lmingw32`. I still keep getting the same errors.. I was able to fix the WinMain Error.. But everything else I couldn't fix.

The command I'm Running to compile:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g src\*.cpp -o build\game.exe -ID:C:\MinGW\include -LD:C:\MinGW\lib -mwindows -lSDL2main -lSDL2_image -lSDL2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common cause of mysterious `undefined reference` errors on MinGW is using libraries compiled for x64 with an x32 compiler, or vice versa. SDL ships both x32 and x64 ones, try the other ones.

> I was able to fix the WinMain Error

Be aware that the intended way of fixing `undefined reference to WinMain@16` is **not** adding `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` and **not** doing `#undef main`. Once you get the right libraries (see the first paragraph), the error should disappear by itself.

Make sure you use `int main(int, char**)` (and not `int main()` nor `void main()`), otherwise it won't work.

> `-ID:C:\MinGW\include -LD:C:\MinGW\lib`

You shouldn't need those flags. Those directories will be searched automatically.

Since you didn't specify any other directories, I assume you placed the SDL files directly into the compiler directories, which isn't a good practice, IMO.

I assume `D:C:` a typo?

> `-mwindows`

The only purpose of this flag (that I know of) is to prevent your app from automatically opening a terminal window for itself, for release builds.